# the height of elegance and sophistication

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please help me with the phrase " the height of elegance and sophistication " in the context. What does it mean ? 
If possible, could anyone paraphrase it into another way to get me understood it better?

> District One is where almost of the city's attractions can be found. Head to the area around Dong Khoi street. Known as Rue Catinat when Viet Nam was part of French Indochina in the early 20th century. It was the height of elegance and sophistication.

Source video: [Ho chi minh city vacation travel guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35Z4GGvCmlU)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic expression, "the height of X" is just another way to express a superlative, the *most* or the *best* of something.  So saying that the district was "the height of elegance and sophistication" means that it was *superlatively* elegant and sophisticated.

Other examples:

> Yves Saint Laurent's designs were the **height of fashion** at the time.
>
> He considered his work with the charity to be the **height of his successful career**.

Answer (score 1):

It's a metaphor. Think of it in terms of a vertical scale, from the lowest level to the highest.